# How to correctly structure my JFrame project?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I'm having trouble doing my JFrame project.

Basically, I'm fairly new to Java and I want to improve myself doing some GUI app using simple classes.

I have a main method which instantiates my objects, a JFrame window class, a Panel class & a Story class which describe every function that I will call if you click on the Frame buttons.

My problem is, I don't find a way to use my Story class. I want to call its methods into the Panel but Story already takes a Panel parameter (to call panel components like TextArea & Buttons) so I cannot instantiate it into my Panel class.

Here is a sample of the code :

Main Class :

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    GamePanel myPanel = new GamePanel();
    GameWindow myWindow = new GameWindow(myPanel);
}
}
```

Window Class :

```
public class GameWindow extends JFrame {

private GamePanel p;

public GameWindow(GamePanel p) {
    this.p = p;
    this.setSize(800,600);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setContentPane(this.p);
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public void setPanel(GamePanel panel) {
    this.p = panel;
}
public GamePanel getPanel() {
    return this.p;
}
}
```

Panel Class :

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

// PANEL TITLE MENU
private JPanel titleSection = new JPanel();
private JLabel titleName = new JLabel("TEXT ADVENTURE");
private Font titleFont = new Font("Bradley Hand", Font.BOLD, 50);

// PANEL STARTBUTTON MENU
private JPanel buttonSection = new JPanel();
private JButton buttonStart = new JButton("START");
private Font buttonFont = new Font("Bradley Hand", Font.BOLD, 30);

// PANEL MAINTEXT GAME
private JPanel mainTextSection = new JPanel();
private JTextArea mainTextArea = new JTextArea();
private Font mainTextFont = new Font("Avenir", Font.PLAIN, 20);

// PANEL MAINBUTTONS GAME
private JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
private JButton button1 = new JButton();
private JButton button2 = new JButton();
private JButton button3 = new JButton();
private JButton button4 = new JButton();

// PANEL PLAYERINFO GAME
private JPanel playerInfo = new JPanel();
private JLabel playerHp, playerHpNumber, playerWeapon, playerWeaponName;


// HANDLERS OBJECTS
private TitleHandler tHandler = new TitleHandler();
private ButtonsHandler cHandler = new ButtonsHandler();

// DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR
public GamePanel() {

    this.setBackground(Color.darkGray);

    // TITLE SETUP
    titleSection.setBounds(100,80,600,150);
    titleSection.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
    this.add(titleSection);
    titleName.setForeground(Color.white);
    titleName.setFont(titleFont);
    titleSection.add(titleName);

    // STARTBUTTON SETUP
    buttonSection.setBounds(300,400,200,100);
    buttonSection.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
    this.add(buttonSection);
    buttonStart.setForeground(Color.black);
    buttonStart.setFont(buttonFont);
    buttonStart.addActionListener(tHandler);
    buttonSection.add(buttonStart);
}

public void createGameScreen() {

    // MENU SCREEN DISABLE
    titleSection.setVisible(false);
    buttonSection.setVisible(false);

    // MAINTEXT SETUP
    mainTextSection.setBounds(100,100,600,250);
    mainTextSection.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
    this.add(mainTextSection);
    mainTextArea.setBounds(100,100,600,250);
    mainTextArea.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
    mainTextArea.setForeground(Color.white);
    mainTextArea.setFont(mainTextFont);
    mainTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
    mainTextSection.add(mainTextArea);

    // MAINBUTTONS SETUP
    buttonPanel.setBounds(250,350,300,150);
    buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));
    this.add(buttonPanel);
    button1.setForeground(Color.black);
    button1.setFont(mainTextFont);
    button1.addActionListener(cHandler);
    button1.setActionCommand("c1");
    buttonPanel.add(button1);
    button2.setForeground(Color.black);
    button2.setFont(mainTextFont);
    //button2.addActionListener(cHandler);
    //button2.setActionCommand("c2");
    buttonPanel.add(button2);
    button3.setForeground(Color.black);
    button3.setFont(mainTextFont);
    //button3.addActionListener(cHandler);
    //button3.setActionCommand("c3");
    buttonPanel.add(button3);
    button4.setForeground(Color.black);
    button4.setFont(mainTextFont);
    //button4.addActionListener(cHandler);
    //button4.setActionCommand("c4");
    buttonPanel.add(button4);

    // PLAYERINFO SETUP
    playerInfo.setBounds(100,25,600,50);
    playerInfo.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
    playerInfo.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4));
    this.add(playerInfo);
    playerHp = new JLabel("HP :");
    playerHp.setFont(mainTextFont);
    playerHp.setForeground(Color.white);
    playerInfo.add(playerHp);
    playerHpNumber = new JLabel();
    playerHpNumber.setFont(mainTextFont);
    playerHpNumber.setForeground(Color.white);
    playerInfo.add(playerHpNumber);
    playerWeapon = new JLabel("Weapon :");
    playerWeapon.setFont(mainTextFont);
    playerWeapon.setForeground(Color.white);
    playerInfo.add(playerWeapon);
    playerWeaponName = new JLabel("None");
    playerWeaponName.setFont(mainTextFont);
    playerWeaponName.setForeground(Color.white);
    playerInfo.add(playerWeaponName);
    repaint();
}

public void setMainTextArea(String t) {
    this.mainTextArea.setText(t);
}
public void setButton1(String t) {
    this.button1.setText(t);
}
public void setButton2(String t) {
    this.button2.setText(t);
}
public void setButton3(String t) {
    this.button3.setText(t);
}
public void setButton4(String t) {
    this.button4.setText(t);
}


public class ButtonsHandler implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        defineEvent(e);
    }

    public void defineEvent(ActionEvent e) {
        if (true) {
            // call Story functions for test
        } else {

        }
    }
}

// NESTED CLASS FOR HANDLING MENU STARTBUTTON
public class TitleHandler implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        createGameScreen();
    }
}
}
```

Story Class :

```
public class Story {

protected String position = "Start";
protected GamePanel p;

public Story() {

}

// FUNCTIONS
public void gameStart() {
    this.position = "Start";
    p.setMainTextArea("...\nYou're waking up in a forest.\nYour head hurts a lot.\nWhy are you here ?\n\n" +
            "You decide to explore through the forest, looking for clues.");
    p.setButton1(">");
}

// GETTERS & SETTERS
public String getPosition() {
    return position;
}
public GamePanel getP() {
    return p;
}

public void setGamePanel(GamePanel p) {
    this.p = p;
}
}
```

(Sorry, seems like I have some parenthesis trouble with the code here)

I guess my code is badly structured but I can't find a way to separate my Story & my Panel class.

Any help will be appreciated! :)

Comment: Since you have a Story class, isn't it better to return the data as string wherever needed instead of having panel parameter inside it. This just makes your Story class more dependent which you might want to avoid to maintain a cleaner code. Also it would be better if you follow an MVC pattern which will not only simplify your, but also make any additions/update in code hassle free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take a look at MVC (Model View Controller) architecture, in your case I believe you can use its simpler sister called MV (Model View).

The reason of your pain is that you mixed model (the Story) and the view (Panel) into the same class (Story.java). Your model can be (relatively) easily implemented with the State Machine pattern.

You will likely need to implement the Observer pattern as well, where the Observer is the Panel and the Observable is the Story. You can have the GamePanel implement PropertyChangeListener and your model (Story) will trigger **propertyChange** event every time its state changes. More on this you can find [at this article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DesignPatternObserver/article.html).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice. Just checked out and it seems to work. Just a quick question ; I'm doing my View and my Model without parameter, so my Controller take both of them and treat with both simultaneously. Is it the correct way ? I saw that many people have their own way to do mvc !

Comment: You can probably get away without Controller, this is more needed in Web applications. The controller functions will mostly be implemented in your model, if you use state machine pattern together.